# Any idea how to enforce utf8 within a document

Tags: c#, utf-8

I am creating an xml document and atttempting to store at as utf8. However, i am receiving a non utf8  apostrophe within the stored document.

eg : `<Name=Dave t="Owner(e.g pete’s)">`

I have tried the follwoing

```
`System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

var docX  = encoding.GetBytes(vdd.ToString());

System.IO.StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(pathAndFileName, false, encoding);

string myString = encoding.GetString(docX);

s.Write(myString);
```

`

Which should have been overkill, but the '’' inside of the brackets is still showing. I have also tried htmlencode, which didn't help.

The xml reads fine as utf8 in notepad++, but the ’ character is not parsing on all of my clients systems.

Help please.....

Comment: What do you mean by a "non-UTF8 apostrophe"? UTF-8 can represent every character present in Unicode...

Comment: Do you actually get an exception?

Comment: The example you posted is not XML; XML elements must have a tag name, and attributes must be quoted. Yours have neither.

Comment: @Dour High Arch D'oh! Good catch!

Comment: Using xmlwriter and utf8 encoding i get the output

&lt;Answer score="4" answerCode="5" term="Relations (inc. Parent’s)" /&gt; 

This ordinarily appears as 

<Answer score="4" answerCode="5" term="Relations (inc. Parent’s)" />

Comment: @Jon Skeet Sorry, the apostrophe fails to parse when you run it through the regex tools for validating utf8 characters, found here
(http://keithdevens.com/weblog/archive/2004/Jun/29/UTF-8.regex)

It is not failing to parse on my xml parser, either in java, c++ or c# but a 3rd party is struggling with this character.

Comment: @Dour High Arch The top sample is a snippet of xml, the code is the c# used for writing it to a document. Apologies for the confusion, i am not trying to parse the xml, but am trying to output it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Dour noted something I missed in all the confusion; the sample you pasted is not XML at all, and therefore will not parse. My answer still applies insofar as 'html encoding' and UTF8 encoding were the wrong roads to be going down here.

---

It's difficult to tell exactly what your problem is, but I've tried to eliminate some of the possibilities and come up with a possibility: the `’` is causing your XML not to be parsed correctly.

This is not an encoding problem. As The Skeet notes, UTF8 can represent all Unicode characters, including that one. Instead, this is an... umm... an encoding problem. That is: a XML data encoding problem.

The character should be **attribute encoded**, not **html encoded**

What API are you using to build the XML? That should be done for you, so you don't need to worry about what to encode, how, and why. But if you **attribute encode** the `’` character, I think your problem will cease.

Assuming I understand your problem...

Comment: Using xmlwriter and utf8 encoding i get the output

&lt;Answer score="4" answerCode="5" term="Relations (inc. Parent’s)" /&gt;

This ordinarily appears as

<Answer score="4" answerCode="5" term="Relations (inc. Parent’s)" />

Comment: I have tried using xmlwriter, streamwriter and xdocument.save... In all cases the ’ still appears in the returned xml.

Comment: @Jon Skeet The ’ character is part of a string pulled from a datatable. I tried to replace the values with the ciorrect encoding, but VS fails to find it....

Answer (score 0):

```
<Name=Dave t="Owner(e.g pete’s)">
```

This is not XML, the '=' is illegal for a tag name. If it's supposed to be an attribute it must be quoted. It's also unterminated and has no XML declaration; if this is what you're trying to output, you're not outputting XML. The ’ character is allowed both in UTF-8 and XML attribute values.

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
var docX = encoding.GetBytes(vdd.ToString());
```

`docX` is a byte array of the UTF-8 bytes in `vdd`. If `vdd` contains any non-Unicode points they will be discarded.

```
System.IO.StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(pathAndFileName, false, encoding);
```

You're opening a UTF-8-encoded output stream, fair enough...

```
string myString = encoding.GetString(docX);
```

Now you're converting your UTF-8-encoded array back into a C# string. Why?

```
s.Write(myString);
```

Now you're writing the C# string back to a UTF-8 stream, which does a second UTF-8 conversion. This makes no sense, please explain what you're trying to accomplish.

> the ’ character is not parsing on all of my clients systems

Then your clients system is not accepting UTF-8. Either fix it, or find out what encoding they are accepting and use that.

Comment: Thanks for the walkthrough, the code converts to utf8 so often is that I'm trying to make sure that the  ’  character is definately utf8, as according to the regex code for validating utf8 it does not appear to be. The xml was a quick sample (more aimed at showing where the character appeared) so was not too bothered about full structure.

Replacing the  ’ char with a ' in the xml allows it to parse fine at their end. However, having managed to parse the xml doc in c++, java and c# app i am more than happy to assume that the problem is their parser not the  ’ .